# Using MultipleView controller in Container view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am building an iOS app which have its many different views and difficult also.

I have a tab bar with 4 pages that are as under

1. Account
2. Main Page
3. Wallet
4. My Lists

when User will tap on List (4th num option), my app needs to show a Header with segmented control (or any top bar like control not decided yet) I want to move Multiple ViewController here . let say top bar has 5 buttons as under

1. Home list
2. Relative list
3. Friends list
4. office list
5. clients list

For these different list I have made different View controller. that I want to move in the My List (which is Main view controller and will be deal as a Master view controller and will contain above mentioned 5 buttons) In this Master view controller when I click Home list or Friends list button it will move related View controller just below this top bar (button list)

For more clarification see the picture below. And just let me know How can I do this. . How can I make specific area to be taken by child View controller.

[image: See this picture for question]

Comment: Several ways to do this... One approach: "My Lists" tab holds a VC with your segmented control and a container view holding a `UIPageViewController`. When the user selects a segment, tell the PageVC to "go to that page".

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you are a little confuse in using Container view using IB or by programmatically. when You use in IB , you have to simple create a related class for it. Just like You create View Controller by dragging from Object library  and associate it with coca touch UIViewController class.

I will suggest to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq-lHR5ZOW0) tutorial. its quiet simple and easy to understand. 
but the answer of your question is:

Take a UIView just below the top bar as you said in question. You can make it full width and full height however you like. Then create its out let. just like below and use this as

```
@IBOutlet var viewMain: UIView!
```

and just move your Child view controller with this

```
viewMain.addSubview(childViewController)
```

You are done

Answer (score 0):

If SegmentControl views have same design then you do not need separate ViewControllers for each.
If Each list has totally different UI then there are many ways to do this.

1- Use scrollview,its content width will be Screenwidth * number of views.
Just add all the views in scrollView.

For Example you want to add to two views Here is the code

```
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 2, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    let vc1 = your view controller
    vc1.view.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 1, width: scrollView.frame.size.width , height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

    let vc2 = your second viewcontroller
    vc2.view.frame =  CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: 1, width: scrollView.frame.size.width  , height: scrollView.frame.size.height)


    scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
    scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
```

Now if you want to change visible view

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(//Position of your view 1 or 2), y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height), animated: true)
```

2- Use Containers

3- There are very good open source libraries(pods) available as well.One one them is CarbonKit
https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit

Comment: How to do with Containers. let say I have 1 master and 5 different child ViewController. Now I want to show ChildVC1 at startup, and when user click on button in Master, it should now replace ChildVC1 and should show ChildVC2